# Open specific ports of local servers through port forwarding, while block internet access

Tags: networking, ufw

I have some local servers (192.168.0.100 (x1) ~ 192.168.0.110 (x10), respectively, no public IP),
and they are connected to the internet via a gateway server (192.168.0.1, has public IP).

```
Internet---<gw>---switch---<x1>
                    |------<x2>
                    |
                    |   ...
                    |
                    |------<x9>
                    |------<x10>
```

For each local server, two ports are opened (SSH and service port),
and those ports are forwarded to the gateway server,
so that the users can connect to the local server using the forwarded ports.

For example, port 22 of the local server (192.168.0.100) is forwarded to port 10022 of the gateway server, so the users can connect port 10022 of the public IP of the gateway server, to access the local server 192.168.0.100

However, in the current setting, the local servers can access the internet, which is not was intended. Therefore, I want configure UFW to maintain current settings but block internet access from the local servers.

I tried many UFW settings from searches, but all the tries were resulted in either (1) the local server and the gateway loses their connection (2) the local server still connects to the internet.

```
# OK
est13@desktop:~$ ssh -p 10000 gw # Connect to the local server via GW
                                 # GW port 10000 => local server port 22 forwarded
est13@x1:~$                      # OK since port 10000 is allowed

# OK
est13@desktop:~$ ssh gw    # Connect to the gateway
est13@gw:~$                # OK since port 22 of the gateway is allowed

# OK
est13@gw:~$ ssh x1
est13@gw:~$ ssh <public IP> # INTENDED, internet access is OK from the gateway

# NOT OK
est13@gw:~$ ssh x1          # Connect to the local server from the gateway
est13@x1:~$ ssh <public IP>
Password:                   # NOT INTENDED, SHOULD BE BLOCKED
```

The current UFW settings are below.

```
Status: active
Default: deny (incoming), deny (outgoing)

To              Action     From
--              ------     ----
10000:10010     ALLOW IN   Anywhere       # For SSH access to the local servers from outside
10100:10110     ALLOW IN   Anywhere       # For service access to the local servers from outside
22              ALLOW IN   Anywhere       # For SSH access of the gateway server

192.168.0.0/24  ALLOW OUT  192.168.0.1    # Allow GW => local servers
192.168.0.1     ALLOW OUT  192.168.0.0/24 # Allow local servers => GW
```

Any idea will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to explicitly allow outgoing from `192.168.0.1` to `Anywhere` and then after it, drop outgoing from `192.168.0.0/24` to `!` NOT `192.168.0.1` if `--state` is `!` NOT `ESTABLISHED` or `RELATED` ... Make those at the end of the rules set.

Comment: `ALLOW OUT` refers to outbound traffic from the machine itself, not (if I remember correctly) to routed traffic. This means that your final UFW rule doesn't do anything. Look at `allow route` for this.

Comment: BTW, as you already have setup port forwarding on the gateway (I assume using `iptables -t nat`?) then it may be better to add the routing rules there as well, to eliminate possible interference with UFW (which in the end also manages a set of iptables rules).